# Can verbatim be used on contents of an include?

Tags: symfony, twig

I'm sharing templates between client and server and would like to output the raw template inside a script tag which is possible with verbatim.

http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/tags/verbatim.html

However it would be nicer if this could be applied as a filter to the include but it doesn't seem possible?

I'm new to twig so excuse me if i've missed obvious functionality.

Comment: please explan why it would be nicer as a filter. I cannot see the reason

Comment: Have you tried [raw](http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/filters/raw.html)?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I ran into the same problem, and this page came up in my search results. In the time since this question was answered, the Twig developers added this functionality into the library. I figured I should add some details for future searchers.

The functionality to include raw text (aka for client-side templates using the same syntax as Twig) is accomplished with the `source` function.

Ie: `{{ source('path/to/template.html.twig') }}`

http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/functions/source.html

Comment: Awesome, thank you for updating this as I certainly hadn't noticed this update myself.

Answer (score 2):

I was looking for something like this too because I'm using Twig.js for some client-side templating along with Symfony. I was trying to share templates between the server-side and client-side code, so I needed content to be parsed in some cases and treated as verbatim in others, which proved to be a bit tricky.

I couldn't find anything built into Twig to help with this, but luckily, it's pretty easy to extend Twig to get what you're looking for. I implemented it as a function, but you may be able to do it as a filter too.

services.yml

```
statsidekick.twig.include_as_template_extension:
        class: StatSidekick\AnalysisBundle\Twig\IncludeAsTemplateExtension
        tags:
            - { name: twig.extension }
```

IncludeAsTemplateExtension.php

```
<?php
namespace StatSidekick\AnalysisBundle\Twig;

use Twig_Environment;
use Twig_Extension;

class IncludeAsTemplateExtension extends Twig_Extension {

    /**
     * Returns a list of global functions to add to the existing list.
     *
     * @return array An array of global functions
     */
    public function getFunctions() {
        return array(
            new \Twig_SimpleFunction( 'include_as_template', array( $this, 'includeAsTemplate' ), array( 'needs_environment' => true, 'is_safe' => array( 'html' ) ) )
        );
    }

    function includeAsTemplate( Twig_Environment $env, $location, $id ) {
        $contents = $env->getLoader()->getSource( $location );
        return "<script data-template-id=\"{$id}\" type=\"text/x-twig-template\">{$contents}</script>";
    }

    /**
     * Returns the name of the extension.
     *
     * @return string The extension name
     */
    public function getName() {
        return 'include_as_template_extension';
    }
}
```

Usage in Twig file

```
{{ include_as_template( 'Your:Template:here.html.twig', 'template-id' ) }}
```

If you have a Twig file like this:

```
<ul class="message-list">
{% for message in messages %}
    <li>{{ message }}</li>
{% endfor %}
</ul>
```

The output will be this:

```
<script data-template-id="template-id" type="text/x-twig-template">
    <ul class="message-list">
    {% for message in messages %}
        <li>{{ message }}</li>
    {% endfor %}
    </ul>
</script>
```

The work is derived from Kari Söderholm's answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12180568/2065822). Hope that helps!