# Jquery uploader not working In Twig File

Tags: mongodb, symfony, twig

Hi i am working on Symfony 2.4.2.I searched a multifile uploader for my application.

but in my Twig file where i am using this code its not working showing Error.
because of {% %} in twig we are using same syntax. can any one help me to figure out this.

If i am using this in HTML so its working.But i want it into TWIG file in Symfony.

```
<script id="template-upload" type="text/x-tmpl">

{% for (var i=0,file; file=o.files[i]; i++) {  %}

         <tr class="template-upload fade">
            <td>
               <span class="preview"></span>
            </td>
           <td>
            <p class="name">{%=file.name%}</p>
            {% if (file.error) { %}
                <div>
             <span class="label label-danger">Error</span>    {%=file.error%}   </div>
            {% } %}
        </td>
        <td>
            <p class="size">{%=o.formatFileSize(file.size)%}</p>
            {% if (!o.files.error) { %}
                <div class="progress progress-striped active" role="progressbar" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100" aria-valuenow="0">
                <div class="progress-bar progress-bar-success" style="width:0%;">   </div>
                     </div>
                {% } %}
            </td>
            <td>
                 {% if (!o.files.error && !i && !o.options.autoUpload) { %}
                     <button class="btn blue start btn-sm">
                    <i class="fa fa-upload"></i>
                    <span>Start</span>
                    </button>
                {% } %}
                {% if (!i) { %}
                    <button class="btn red cancel btn-sm">
                    <i class="fa fa-ban"></i>
                    <span>Cancel</span>
                   </button>
                {% } %}
            </td>
        </tr>
    {% } %}
 </script>
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Try putting your code between the `autoescape` tag in twig.

```
 {% autoescape false %}
  Everything will be outputted as is in this block
 {% endautoescape %}
```

See this for reference and for more options: 
http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/tags/autoescape.html

**Edit:**

If autoescaping (false) not working for you, then you may use the `source` function. Just output your file to a separate .html file and embed it via the `source` tag: 
http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/functions/source.html

Thanks for this post: 
[How do I include raw HTML files in Symfony2/Twig templates?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7664643/how-do-i-include-raw-html-files-in-symfony2-twig-templates)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can try the "raw" tag. Not sure.

```
{% raw %}
    your code here
{% endraw %}
```